# MS Access is Not Appending Table In Workspace

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, dao

For some reasons this query is not appending the table within the workspace... I have absolutely NO idea why... any help would be so amazing!

```
    Function SaveChanges()
    Dim db As DAO.Database, ws As DAO.Workspace, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Application.Echo False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
        Set db = ws.Databases(0)
            ws.BeginTrans
                Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qry_Cost_Actual_Select_Standard_Save_01"): qdf.Parameters(0) = TempVars![var_FiltrBatchID]: qdf.Execute
                Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qry_Cost_Actual_Select_Standard_Save_02"): qdf.Parameters(0) = TempVars![var_FiltrBatchID]: qdf.Execute
                Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qry_Cost_Actual_Select_Standard_Save_03"): qdf.Parameters(0) = TempVars![var_FiltrBatchID]: qdf.Parameters(1) = TempVars![var_FiltrBatchID]: qdf.Execute
            ws.CommitTrans
    Call BackToMain
ExitHandler:
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Application.Echo True
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
        Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    ws.Rollback
    Resume ExitHandler
End Function
```

Comment: Start by adding `dbFailOnError`: `qdf.Execute dbFailOnError`. Currently, you're silently ignoring errors.

Comment: I am not, on error it will move to the error handler, which has a rollback on the workspace transactions...

Comment: ... You are. `qdf.Execute` only raises errors if you add `dbFailOnError` and silently ignores them otherwise.

Comment: I see what your saying now, in any case I've stepped through it and it isn't actually throwing any errors, its just not writing anything to the table... If i run it outside of VBA it writes the additional lines, but within VBA it does not write anything, and it does not roll back or throw any errors...

Comment: Thank you for your help with the error management, it ended up being an issue with the order of items running where the form wasn't saving changes before running the update query.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was actually with the form not saving before running the table update query. The reason nothing was posting was because I needed to save any changes first (rookie mistake!)... I ran the below code first and the update added the lines perfectly

```
If Me.Dirty Then
    Me.Dirty = False
End If
```

Thank you [Erik A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a) for your help on adding the dbFailOnError piece I missed